# How to create game highscores with names?

Tags: c#

I have a simple game and I want to save highscores with names, then on another form show it, but in descending order of points.
I want to do it with txt file, and saving is ok, I just save like: Adam,200,John,100 etc. Showing them is also not problem but how to sort them? So how can I connect the scores with the names?

Comment: What have you tried? [Sorting numbers for highscores in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143328/sorting-numbers-for-highscores-in-java), [How to Sort a List<> by a Integer stored in the struct my List<> holds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424420/how-to-sort-a-list-by-a-integer-stored-in-the-struct-my-list-holds), and so on all have useful advice on how to store, retreive and sort a key-value pair.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store them in a more obviously structure way. So for example, you could still use a text file, with one entry per line:

```
Adam,200
John,200
```

etc

Then you would *read* them from the file, parse each line into a `HighScoreEntry` object (you'd have to create the `HighScoreEntry` class, of course), and add it to a list. Or use LINQ to do the transformation:

```
var highScoreEntries = File.ReadLines("highscores.txt")
                           .Select(line => HighScoreEntry.FromLine(line))
                           .ToList();
```

Then you can just use:

```
var orderedScores = highScoreEntries.OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Score);
```

Alternatively, you could use something like XML to store the scores, which would provide even more structure, and make some of the parsing slightly easier.

If all of this sounds too difficult, try to identify which exact step is causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create an object that looks like this:

```
public class Player  
{  
    string name;  
    long score; // i assume no decimal points  
    // getters/setters
}
```

And then sort like this:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();  
players.Sort(delegate(Player player1, Player player2) { return player1.score.CompareTo(player2.score); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an static class in your project.
The concept is, writing a class and declear an array inside, I wanna show you a sample:

```
class score

{
    public static int max = 0;
    public static int john = 0;


}
```

now you change the value from anywhere in your project with providing to the class. You can create an array which includes your users names.

Now, It's time to make your new form, and draw lables and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scores = File.ReadLines("scores.txt")
    .Select(line => {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            return new { Name = parts[0], Score = int.Parse(parts[1]) };
        })
    .OrderByDescending(highScore => highScore.Score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try using a

```
 List<Dictionary> myList
```

This basically keeps a pair of keys and values.  What you should be able to sort pretty easily.